# Jenkins - Git - Repository not found

Tags: git, jenkins, gitea

I am trying to run a Jenkins job which checks out code from a Git repository. When I set the GIT repository, I'm getting the next error:

[image: Error]

I am using the next software versions:

- Jenkins 2.289.1 in Windows 7.
- Git client: v2.29.2
- Gitea Versión: 73ce024

User and password is required to access my repositories in Gitea through the web console, so I've added an user/password credential in the repository configuration section.

Checking logs I can see:

[image: Error logs]

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having a similar issue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't solve yet

Answer (score 0):

First - check credentials you are using to get access to gitlab.
Second - check if your username has access to the gitlab group/project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My credentials are right. I'm not accesing to gitlab. I'm trying to access to Gitea, wich we have installed in my company